# How to pass form data to another component through a service?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have a search form on my Angular 2(8) page and I want to gather form data, give it to search service, perform a search/filtering (if needs be) and then pass the results to the rendering somponent, thus navigating user to another page.

Now, in my form.component.html I have:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"
   fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
   // some form fields
   <button 
     type="submit" 
     mat-raised-button 
     color="primary"
     [disabled]="f.invalid">Search</button>
</form>
```

So, the form.component.ts has the onSubmit method:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  const searchForm = form.value as SearchForm;
  console.log(searchForm);
}
```

And this is where my question begins: I want pass data to the searchService, maybe something like:

```
this.searchService.performSearch(searchForm)
  .subscribe(
    () => {
      router.navigate('/results');
    },
    () => { }
    );
```

Then I want to access this data in my search.component.ts:

```
results = Result[];
```

And in the search.component.html:

```
<app-search-item *ngFor="let result of results" [result]="result">
</app-search-item>
```

How can I implement such a behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data while navigating like this:

```
this.router.navigate('/results', { state: result });
```

And you can access the data from the router like this:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
```

Answer (score 1):

from forms component you can just call a method of search service

```
this.serachService.search(input)
```

In search service you can have a results array and get the results

```
results = Results[]
search(input){
// get results from your api here 
 this.http
        .get(`api/search/?name=${term}`).subscribe( res =>{
this.results = res;
 router.navigate('/results');

}
```

In search component you can use this.searchService.results